# Select lines with data to save to pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

My workbook has 4 sheets (1 home page + 3 sheets with tables). In these 3 sheets I would like to add to the code the reading of the last line with data from column B, so as not to have blank lines in the pdf (this causes many unnecessary sheets).

I used this code for my three sheets:

```vb
Sub pdf()  
    Dim n As Integer
    n = Range("B6").End(xlDown).row

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\tempo.pdf", Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End sub
```

Through my formatting, if you don't read the lines with data, it will send the lines that are formatted with "black line".
[image]

Comment: Isn't that default behaviour? If other lines are empty they won't be exported, right? Is it possible that you have some  Print Areas set up in your file, that mess with it?

Comment: @misa Please check my question. I added information above

Comment: You should firstly iterate between the two involved sheets, hide their empty rows, export and unhide (if you need he sheets as they used to be...) them at the end.

Comment: @fane How? I don't understand...because if I charhe Ctrl+shift+ down arrow this method doesn't read the last line, because in vba code it will assume the line number and it isn't always the same because they are daily records (and therefore they may vary)

Comment: I cannot get you, sorry... Did you try testing the code I supplied 7 minutes before (in my answer)?

Comment: What does line 22 [ Set rngH2 = Union(rngH2, sh.Range("B" & i)) ] mean @fane? It's giving error...

Comment: Do you try processing **more than two sheets**?

Comment: @fane Yes, currently I have 7  sheets for processing

Comment: Then, when you asked about processing of two sheets, the supplied code does not work for more of them. 1. Did you test the code on two sheets, **as you asked in your question**? If yes,  didn't it work as you need? If not, **why didn't you test it**? 2. It can be adjusted to process as many sheets as possible, but some rules must be set: If you do not need the hidden rows to be unhidden the code will become even simpler, using a unique `Union` range. If you need the rows to be unhidden, **you should state** that.

Comment: @fane Yes, I tested the code on two sheets (but it didn't work). Furthermore I should adjust the table so that everything appears on the sheet (for a 55% zoom). In my current excel I have 4 auxiliary sheets + 7 sheets (in this order and these are the pages I need to save in excel).

Comment: "it didn't work" does not say anything! Does it raise an error? If so, what error on which code line? If not, what does it do against what you want it doing?

Comment: The code didn't strip the lines without data

Comment: Please define what does **lines without data** mean. The supplied code considers such lines, **the ones not having any data on the whole row**. Is that your case? If yes, is the content of a sheet concentrated **in a single page**? If not, the pages resulted from the exceeding columns may look strange, but this aspect was not mentioned in your question.

Comment: Currently, lines without data meaning blank cells

Comment: What is the fit to apply to 7 sheets? I think, now I need only this.

Comment: I am afraid you do not know very well what you need, no offence... At least, not able to explain it as it should. We are not mind readers... Why wasting my time if you cannot answer simple clarification questions? Do you understand what **blank cells** means? Do you want skipping the blank cells from the sheet, or hiding the rows which contain **only blank cells**? How to need "the fit to apply to 7 sheets" if the one supplied (for you, I do not need it) to process two sheets  does not work as you want?

Comment: Alternative way to solve this would be deleting the format of the empty lines - you have them formatted (the bordering) and that is why your current macro is exporting them. Delete the formatting and you'll get pdf only with values. If you really need to have the borders there change the format from range to Table and then every time you add new line of data the border will be added, but you won't have it at empty cells.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next adapted code. It iterates between the two involved sheets, hide the empty rows, publish them and unhide the rows at the end:

```
Sub pdf()
 Dim n As Long, sh As Worksheet, rngH1 As Range, rngH2 As Range
 Dim i As Long, k As Long

 'firstly, place the empty rows in Union ranges and hide them:
 For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
     k = k + 1 'increment the variable to use the appropriate empty rows range
     n = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row   'last row on column B:B
     For i = 1 To n
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.rows(i)) = 0 Then
            If k = 1 Then
                If rngH1 Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngH1 = sh.Range("B" & i)
                Else
                    Set rngH1 = Union(rngH1, sh.Range("B" & i))
                End If
            Else
                If rngH2 Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngH2 = sh.Range("B" & i)
                Else
                    Set rngH2 = Union(rngH2, sh.Range("B" & i))
                End If
            End If
        End If
     Next
     If k = 1 And Not rngH1 Is Nothing Then rngH1.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     If k = 2 And Not rngH2 Is Nothing Then rngH2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Next sh
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:="C:\tempo.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
  
  'Unhide the previously hidden rows:
  If Not rngH1 Is Nothing Then rngH1.EntireRow.Hidden = False
  If Not Not rngH2 Is Nothing Then rngH2.EntireRow.Hidden = False
 End Sub
```